# Is Hanuman adept in the Natya Sastra?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, hanuman, natya-shastra

Can anyone suggest a reference that says Anjaneya or any other son of Marut / Vayu is adept in the Natya-sastra?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any puranic reference to say Hanuman was adept in dance? Alternatively, do we have any other reference saying the other sons of Vayu like Bhima or Vyasaraya was adept in dance?